# error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I just installed Oracle database, and it was missing the `SCOTT` schema. So I am trying to generate it myself. I got the sql script of Scott schema, but when I try to run the query

```sql
CREATE USER SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY tiger;
```

it displays the following error

> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle.

Basically it is not allowing me to create a user `SCOTT`. Why is that, and how can I fix my problem?

Comment: That is impossible to have in `11g`, you ought to be on `12c`.

Comment: Maybe you installed an 11g client, but you're connecting to a 12c database? What exactly did you install?

Comment: Append C## before username.

Comment: I am using `19c` but still facing same issue. any suggestion?

Answer (score 499):

99.9% of the time the error `ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name` means you are logged into the CDB when you should be logged into a PDB. For example, if you used the default 19c installation settings, you should login to ORCLPDB (the PDB) instead of ORCL (the CDB).

---

**DANGER** - If you insist on creating users the wrong way, follow the steps below.

Setting undocumented parameters like this (as indicated by the leading underscore) should only be done under the direction of Oracle Support. Changing such parameters without such guidance may invalidate your support contract. So do this at your own risk.

Specifically, if you set `"_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true`, some data dictionary changes will be made with the column ORACLE_MAINTAINED set to 'Y'. Those users and objects will be incorrectly excluded from some DBA scripts. And they may be incorrectly included in some system scripts.

If you are OK with the above risks, and don't want to create common users the correct way, run this command before creating the user:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

[I found the answer here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_65096_create_user_12c_without_c_prefix.htm)

Comment: How to deal with the same error during Data Miner installation? This query doesn't help then

Comment: Worked for me on 12c. Thanks !

Comment: Be aware, it is a **hidden parameter** and to be used only when recommended by Oracle support.

Comment: It is dangerous to use underscore (hidden) parameters in Production systems, as it may invalidate your Support contract. So you should advise people to set them without giving the appropriate warning.

Comment: this is wrong and not supported in oracle, I have used it and it caused another internal issues.

Comment: Solved on 18c!!

Comment: It works on Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: Worked on Oracle 19c

Comment: @APC why it is dangerous ?

Comment: @Victor - Because we're only allowed to change them when directed to do so by Oracle Support. Like I said, setting undocumented parameters off our own bat may invalidate our support contract. More generally, Oracle's default settings for documented and undocumented parameters are usually sound for all applications, and don't need changing. Tweaking underscore parameters appeals to people who enjoy the thrill of arcane access, which is the worst reason to tweak them. But if you don't have a support contract to worry about, you are free to risk damaging your system in any way you choose ;-)

Comment: why don't you show how to fix it the proper way then?

Comment: refer to the other answer below, it shows the way to log into PDB and what it means

Comment: With the free XE I could not get the PDBADMIN account to log in. I have been fighting this issue for two days! When you are on an educational course or you want to experiment with local oracle DB this was the only solution for me. I am sorry only that when I read that this is highly not recommended by Oracle, I ignored it. For future trainees just run this line of code and create your new empty database!

Answer (score 111):

> I just installed oracle11g
>
> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle

No, you have installed **Oracle 12c**. That error could only be on `12c`, and cannot be on `11g`.

Always check your **database version** up to 4 decimal places:

```
SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

[Oracle 12c multitenant container database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89235) has:

- a root container(**CDB**)
- and/or zero, one or many pluggable databases(**PDB**).

You must have created the database as a **container database**. While, you are trying to create user in the container, i.e. **CDB$ROOT**, however, you should create the user in the **PLUGGABLE database**.

You are not supposed to create application-related objects in the container, the container holds the metadata for the pluggable databases. You should use the pluggable database for you general database operations. Else, do not create it as container, and not use **multi-tenancy**. However, 12cR2 onward you cannot create a non-container database anyway.

And most probably, the **sample schemas** might have been already installed, you just need to **unlock** them in the pluggable database.

For example, if you created pluggable database as `pdborcl`:

```
sqlplus SYS/password@PDBORCL AS SYSDBA

SQL> ALTER USER scott ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY tiger;

sqlplus scott/tiger@pdborcl

SQL> show user;
USER is "SCOTT"
```

To show the PDBs and connect to a pluggable database from root container:

```
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT

SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 ORCLPDB                        READ WRITE NO

SQL> alter session set container = ORCLPDB;

Session altered.

SQL> show con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
ORCLPDB
```

I suggest read, **[Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)**

---

**Note**: Answers suggesting to use the `_ORACLE_SCRIPT` hidden parameter to set to true is dangerous in a production system and might also invalidate your support contract. Beware, without consulting Oracle support **DO NOT use hidden parameters**.

Comment: Above link "Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps" is broken. New link: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/post_inst_task.htm#LADBI8084

Comment: @Heri Are you sure? Because it's working fine [Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)

Comment: The default PDB name for Oracle 18c XE is "XEPDB1".

Comment: Why doing things the simple way, when you can do it Oracle way ‍♂️

Comment: I am using 19c but still facing same issue. any suggestion?

Comment: I am running 19c and the answer from @LalitKumarB worked for me.

Answer (score 99):

In Oracle 12c and above, we have two types of databases:

1. Container DataBase (CDB), and
2. Pluggable DataBase (PDB).

If you want to create a user, you have two possibilities:

1. You can create a "container user" aka "common user".
   Common users belong to CBDs as well as to current and future PDBs. It means they can perform operations in Container DBs or Pluggable DBs according to assigned privileges.

   `create user c##username identified by password;`
2. You can create a "pluggable user" aka "local user".
   Local users belong only to a single PDB. These users may be given administrative privileges, but only for that PDB inside which they exist. For that, you should connect to pluggable datable like that:

   `alter session set container = nameofyourpluggabledatabase;`

   and there, you can create user like usually:

   `create user username identified by password;`

Don't forget to specify the tablespace(s) to use, it can be useful during import/export of your DBs. See this for more information about it https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503

Comment: This answer's style is my favourite, quick to use.

Answer (score 30):

```
SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;  
SQL> create user sec_admin identified by "Chutinhbk123@!";
```

Answer (score 17):

If your goal is to create an Oracle user and then use it to do stuff with your DB you probably want to consider doing this:

- log as sysdba
- create a pdb (a.k.a. pluggable database)
- create a user for your pdb

What follows assume you are working with a db in localhost, if not simply change "localhost" with your db uri.

### Sample code

Log as sysdba:

```
$ sqlplus sys/<your_admin_pws>@localhost as sysdba
```

then execute this:

```
create pluggable database MYDATABASE
admin user Scott identified by tiger;
file_name_convert = ('/pdbseed/', '/mydatabase/')
;

alter pluggable database MYDATABASE open;
```

then you may want to grant some permission to user Scott: log out from @localhost and log back in as sysdba to your new db

```
$ sqlplus sys/<your_admin_pws>@localhost/MYDATABASE as sysdba
```

and grant Scott whatever permission you want, e.g.

```
grant connect to Scott;
grant create view to Scott;
grant create table to Scott;
grant create trigger to Scott;
```

now you are good to go: you have an empty database instance and a user. Just log in by doing

```
$ sqlplus Scott/tiger@localhost/MYDATABASE
```

### Bonus

I had problem with tablespaces and quotas after that.
Log with `sqlplus sys/<your_admin_pws>@localhost/MYDATABASE as sysdba`

You can list all tablespaces with

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, STATUS, CONTENTS FROM USER_TABLESPACES;
```

You can create a new tablespace with

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TABLESPACENAME DATAFILE 'tablespace_datafile.dat' SIZE 10M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 200M;
```

You can drop your broken tablespaces with

```
Drop tablespace TABLESPACENAME including contents and datafiles;
```

You can grant "access" to the tablespace to Scott with

```
alter user Scott quota unlimited on TABLESPACENAME;
```

N.B. `quota unlimited` is probably a bad practice, check oracle docs on how to limit user's quota

Answer (score 9):

[image]
under multinant oracle version 12 or higher , there are two types of users:

1. global users, which belong to the CBD container. to create a user in this container you must do Create user `c##username identified by passwod;`
2. local users: which belong to the PDBS databases (are elements which relate to the parent CBD containers). the syntax you used matches the creation of local users.

if you are in pluggable database(PDBS)  do this to solve your problem :

```
create user c##Scott identified by tiger;
```

note : you must add **c##** before the username.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, after default oracle installation, I first connected to `orcl` which cause the problem. And reconnected to `orclpdb` (Pluggable DataBase, PDB) resolve the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 These details are useful for people new to Oracle. I'm going to steal some of your answer and edit it into the accepted answer. (Unfortunately, most people won't scroll down to see your new answer because this thread if full of bad information.)

Comment: For me this worked. Don't use SID, use Service name.

Comment: For Oracle Database 21c Express Edition (XE), use the Service Name for connecting to the PDB, default is xepdb1.

Answer (score 6):

this part may fix your problem.

> alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;

follow this:

```
> sqlplus /nolog
> connect sys / as sysdba
> alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;
> create user user1 identified by 1;
```

and the user is created..

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea, as described in the accepted answer.

Comment: @JonHeller so what is ur solution and still the accepted answer is null.

Comment: There are multiple other answers, including answers that are almost identical to this one.

Answer (score 3):

Advice for docker users getting this error:

I got same error trying to create docker image of Oracle19c and the cause was exactly what accepted answer says. My docker image was intended as copy of original database for testing and development in isolated environment so I was aimed at the best possible similarity with original. Unfortunately the original database was configured as nonCDB single-instance database which is not default setting in [standard Oracle image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/oracle.19.3.0-ee/oracledb19c/oracle.19.3.0-ee/oracle19.3.0-ee/images/sha256-2e76fb433e5bfdcea00c08ffbe96541dc32677463e95fac40cb7bb6289bf4f7b?context=explore).

First I tried [alternative image](https://hub.docker.com/r/doctorkirk/oracle-19c) where it was supported but it has another drawbacks (twice larger, hardcoded VOLUME).

Finally I pulled out `$ORACLE_BASE/*.sh` scripts from both original and alternative image, analyzed differences and applied relevant differences onto original scripts. The essential change was in `dbca.rsp.tmpl` file and in removing usage of `$ORACLE_PDB` env reconfiguring `alter system` startup SQL scripts, also some further related changes such as in healthcheck must be performed.

Then oracle successfully started in nonCDB mode. It can be verified trying `create user foo identified by foo;` as `system` user (which succeeds) or the `select name, cdb, con_id from v$database;` (which returns `cdb=0`).

Answer (score 2):

Might be, more safe alternative to `"_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true` is to change `"_common_user_prefix"` from `C##` to an empty string. When it's null - any name can be used for common user. Found [there](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001370.htm).

During changing that value you may face another issue - ORA-02095 - parameter cannot be modified, that can be fixed in a several ways, based on your configuration ([source](https://itsiti.com/ora-02095-specified-initialization-parameter-cannot-be-modified/)).

So for me worked that:

```
alter system set _common_user_prefix = ''; scope=spfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when I dropped a SQL script .sql into the /opt/oracle/scripts/startup directory. Any .sql or .sh scripts in this directory are automatically ran by /opt/oracle/runUserScripts.sh. SQL scripts are ran under sysdba - which may not always be appropriate - while .sh scripts are ran under the current user. There are two options:

1. put a suitable CONNECT statement at the start of the SQL srcript.
2. Move the .sql script out of the startup directory and run it from another localtion via a .sh script in /opt/oracle/scripts/startup using the command: `sqlplus system/<password>@<pluggable> @<filename>.sql`.

Hope this helps someone. Luck.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this

```
ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = true;

CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY mu123;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO myuser;

ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = false;
```

using above answers.
I am studying on Oracle 21c XE.
This worked in SQL Developer.

Comment: While this solution "works", it is not how you're supposed to use Oracle's multitenant architecture, and it may lead to problems in the future. Regular users should be created on a PDB, but instead you are creating a common user on the CDB root without the standard "C##" name prefix. And that undocumented parameter will make Oracle think your user is an Oracle-maintained account, which means a DBA in the future will probably make a mistake with your user. The real answer is to ensure you're logging into the PDB for most tasks.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple and sure shot solution for creating new user in oracle db and login into it and running DDL queries.

The Problem ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

SQL> create user testdb identified by testpassword;
create user testdb identified by testpassword

**Step 1:** SQL> alter session set container=xepdb1;

```
Session altered.
```

**Step 2:**

```
SQL> create user testdb identified by testpassword;
User created.
```

**Step 3:** `GRANT CREATE SESSION TO testdb;`

Note: if you will not run step 3 you will get "ORA-01045: user xxx lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied"

**Step 4:** `grant all privileges to testdb;`
Note: if you will not run step 4 you will get "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"

You can use following config in java application/sqldeveloper connection

```
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
username: testdb
password: testpassword
```

Service Name = XEPDB1 (not SID)

Answer (score -1):

I followed default installation and. I used following for connecting to the `oracle 21c` from `sqlplus`:
replace `orapass` with your password and `orclpdb` with your pluggable database, which is also a `servicename`.

```
sqlplus system/orapass@localhost:1521/orclpdb
```

within `orclpdb` you can create users `abc` with password `xyz` in normal manner without any workaround.

```
D:\>sqlplus system/orapass@localhost:1521/orclpdb   

 ...

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> CREATE USER abc IDENTIFIED BY xyz;

User created.

SQL>
```

you can then connect to new user using:

```
sqlplus abc/xyz@orclpdb
```

or

`sqlplus abc/xyz@localhost:1521/orclpdb`

you can also add entry to `$ORACLE_HOME\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora`

```
ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =DESKTOP-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

**`DESKTOP-PC`** is name of your PC

Answer (score -2):

Create user dependency upon the database connect tools

```
sql plus
SQL> connect as sysdba;
Enter user-name: sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> ALTER USER hr account unlock identified by hr;
User altered
 then create user on sql plus and sql developer
```

Comment: Could you please format your code properly and give some context why this solves the problem better than the other answers?