# List of all the User excluding default Users

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I required list of all the users excluding the default oracle users.

```
Select Username from all_users;
```

This query will give me the result , but I want only manually created users. As there are 50+ users in my database I can't traverse through each and every user.

I tried :

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/List_of_default_database_users From here I got list of all default users so whether I required to skip all the users using where clause in above query like

```
Select Username from all_users where Username NOT IN ('List All Default
Users Given By Oracle');
```

Or is there any quick way to do it ?

-Nagendra

Comment: From [this Oracle documentation](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3560595?start=0&tstart=0) the answer would seem to be mostly no.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Oracle 12c r1, you can use the new ORACLE_MAINTAINED column in ALL_USERS and DBA_USERS views

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DDD25C8F-7EC9-46BC-ABEA-529C64FA09E2.htm

e.g.

```
select * from dba_tables where owner in 
 (select username from all_users where oracle_maintained = 'N')
```

should give you the list of tables owned by non-internal Oracle users.

Comment: Doesn't work, all users have `Y` in oracle_maintained column, despite some of them been created by me

Comment: @AdriánJaramillo Did you create the users with the undocumented parameter `"_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490385/409172)? If you used that parameter, the `ORACLE_MAINTAINED` column will be set incorrectly. Unfortunately, there's a lot of bad advice for creating users out there.

Answer (score 7):

As per Oracle Database 12c, these are the list of default users to avoid and get the detail of rest all other users.

please verify at below link to know more:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/startrdb.htm#NTDBI2845

```
select username from dba_users where username not in ('ANONYMOUS'
,'APEX_040200'
,'APEX_PUBLIC_USER'
,'APPQOSSYS'
,'AUDSYS'
,'BI'
,'CTXSYS'
,'DBSNMP'
,'DIP'
,'DVF'
,'DVSYS'
,'EXFSYS'
,'FLOWS_FILES'
,'GSMADMIN_INTERNAL'
,'GSMCATUSER'
,'GSMUSER'
,'HR'
,'IX'
,'LBACSYS'
,'MDDATA'
,'MDSYS'
,'OE'
,'ORACLE_OCM'
,'ORDDATA'
,'ORDPLUGINS'
,'ORDSYS'
,'OUTLN'
,'PM'
,'SCOTT'
,'SH'
,'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA'
,'SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR'
,'SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR'
,'SYS'
,'SYSBACKUP'
,'SYSDG'
,'SYSKM'
,'SYSTEM'
,'WMSYS'
,'XDB'
,'SYSMAN'
,'RMAN'
,'RMAN_BACKUP'
,'OWBSYS'
,'OWBSYS_AUDIT'
,'APEX_030200'
,'MGMT_VIEW'
,'OJVMSYS');
```

Answer (score 4):

you could possible do something with the creation date, the likelihood is that the system users would all have been created when the DB was setup, the additional users may have been created on following days/weeks/months. So a query that shows all the users created after the min created date might help you.

```
SELECT username 
  FROM dba_users 
 WHERE TRUNC(created) > (SELECT MIN(TRUNC(created)) 
                           FROM dba_users);
```

Comment: Yes. That can be a workaround but my hard luck. All the users in my database were created on same date. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this retrieving the users that was created after the database create date

```
SELECT usr.username
  FROM sys.dba_users usr
 WHERE usr.created > (SELECT created FROM sys.v_$database)
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle 12c You can use this :

```
select username from all_users where oracle_maintained = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

select name
from system.logstdby$skip_support
where action = 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).