# In Oracle 12c, I could not create a user name, after connecting it to database

Tags: database, oracle, command-prompt, oracle12c

I just installed my Oracle 12c, connected it to database successfully.

1. I could not create a user (in CDB). 
   [image: This was the error i am receiving.]

So, i tried to create user name through PDB. But even PDB is not working.
I am new to Oracle.

After DB was connected successfully, We cans see message like,
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64 bit production. But after this i could see some more matter regarding production of OLAP, Data Mining etc......in some of the youtube videos. i could not get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle)

Comment: DO NOT CREATE USERS in the CDB. open your orclpdb, connect to it, THEN create your user.

Answer (score 5):

With Oracle 12c, when you connect to the root container (as you did above), you are not able to create "typical" users. In the root container, you're only able to create "common" users (based off of a default installation and no parameter changes, users that start with C## - e.g. c##joe). Common users are available in every PDB that you have and create at some later point.

On the other hand, if you switch to a PDB, you can then create your "typical" users.

SQL> show pdbs

Switch to one of them:
SQL> alter session set container=XXXX;

Create your "typical" user should work now:
SQL> create user scott identified by tiger ...

A user created in a PDB is only available to log into the specific PDB it was created in (unlike a common user which can log into all pdbs).

-Jim