# How can I force flyway to clean my docker oracle database?

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle12c, flyway

I've downloaded the official oracle docker image for Oracle Database EE. I've got a flyway configuration and often run `flyway:clean` against the locally installed XE version of the database. However flyway tells me it is not allowed to clean the database in the docker image, but it can migrate it.

Is there a way to force flyway to clean the oracle db?

*To answer the questions from the comments:*

Here's the error message when running flyway through maven:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Clean not supported on Oracle for system schema "SCHEMA_OWNER"! It must not be changed in any way except by running an Oracle-supplied script! -> [Help 1]
```

The user I connect with was created with `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;`

Comment: 1) What is the error message from Flyway? 2) Which user are you connecting as? 3) If connecting as a custom user, how was the user created and did you by any chance use the `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;` workaround for ORA-65096, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490385/6797663

Comment: @codemonkey I answered your questions by updating the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flyway will [throw this exception](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/4b26f8c318dacf7e76a5000156fb2685f8f0ed51/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/oracle/OracleSchema.java#L95-L98) if the current schema is considered a system schema:

```
@Override
protected void doClean() throws SQLException {
    if (isSystem()) {
        throw new FlywayException("Clean not supported on Oracle for system schema " + database.quote(name) + "! " +
                "It must not be changed in any way except by running an Oracle-supplied script!");
    }
```

A schema is considered to be a system schema if it in a list of [known default schemas](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/4b26f8c318dacf7e76a5000156fb2685f8f0ed51/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/oracle/OracleDatabase.java#L309-L360) or has [`ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'Y'`](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/4b26f8c318dacf7e76a5000156fb2685f8f0ed51/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/oracle/OracleDatabase.java#L360).

Creating the user with `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;` sets `ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'Y'` for the user / schema.

There are two kinds of database in Oracle 12c: a Container Database (CDB) and a Pluggable Database (PDB). This is to support [Multitenancy](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html).

You are currently creating the user in the CDB, which would be a common user across all PDBs. In that case, you must either prefix the user name with `c##`:

```
create user c##scott identified by tiger;
```

or use the `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;`, otherwise you will get the error:

```
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle
```

The alternative is to connect to a PDB and create a local user there (no prefix required and the user will only exists in that PDB), e.g.:

```
sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1@ORCLPDB1 as sysdba

create user scott identified by tiger;
```

The update the Flyway url to connect to that PDB as that user:

```
-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle-ee:1521/orclpdb1.localdomain -user="scott" -password=tiger
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! However I don't seem to be able to connect to the PDB using it's SID (as described here: https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-database-enterprise-edition/plans/08cf8677-bb8f-453c-b667-6b0c24a388d4?tab=instructions). I can only approach the database as a service with this connect string: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:32769/ORCLPDB1.localdomain`

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. By default, you can only connect to a PDB using a service name. However, you can set `USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener=on` in the `listener.ora` file and then update the listener with `lsnrctl reload`. See https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1#jdbc-connections-to-pdbs

Comment: It's now problem for me now, so I'm not messing with the container ;)

Comment: `Creating the user with alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true; sets ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'Y' for the user / schema.` aah, of course, of course, how could I not know this...