# django tutorial: testcase failed to create testuser on oracle express database

Tags: django, oracle, testcase

Note: I have tried the solution from [error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle)

I am following the tutorial from django [a link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial05/). When i trying to test the testcase using "py manage.py test polls" i get this:

```
    C:\Users\user\Documents\user_django_projects\mysite>py manage.py test polls
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
    Failed (ORA-01543: tablespace 'TEST_SYSTEM' already exists)
    It appears the test database, test_system, already exists. Type 'yes' to delete it, or 'no' to cancel: yes
    Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
    Creating test user...
    Failed (ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name)
    Got an error creating the test user: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

django can't seem to create a temp user on my local oracle express database. Can someone help me sort it out?

Comment: @KostasCharitidis Hi, I have seen that but I am unsure what to do to fix the issue. I tried following: 1) Open CMD type sqlplus and hit enter

2) Connect from system login

3) Run command : alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

Comment: @KostasCharitidis but it still failed. I am not sure what i need to change in the test class so that when django automated testing fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to sqlplus as sys

```
sqlplus "sys AS SYSDBA"
```

Create a PDB account

```
SQL> alter session set container = XEPDB1;

Session altered.

SQL> create user djangousername identified by djangopassword;

User created.

SQL> grant all privileges to django;

Grant succeeded.
```

*if you using Oracle 12 change `XEPDB1` to `ORCLPDB`*

Now you can connect to Database with sqldeveloper with username and password above and `enter code here`**Service Name** is `XEPDB1` or `ORCLPDB`

Change your database settings at mysite/mysite/settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'localhost:1521/XEPDB1',
        'USER': 'djangousername ',
        'PASSWORD': 'djangopassword',
    }
}
```

Now run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

```
python manage.py test polls
```