# Which user can execute SHOW PDBS on Oracle 18.4?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle18c, oracle-xe-18.4

I'm struggling with creating users in Oracle XE 18.4 when using the [official docker image](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331148/34088) suggests to run the command `SHOW PDBS` but when I connect as user `SYSTEM`, I don't have the permissions to run this:

```
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> show pdbs
SP2-0382: The SHOW PDBS command is not available
```

`help show` will list it as valid option, though. I can't login as `SYS` or `PDBADMIN` (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied).

I tried to reset the passwords using `bash /opt/oracle/setPassword.sh new_password` but that doesn't help.

What do I need to do to run `show pdbs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SHOW.html#GUID-6BB1499D-E537-43D1-A209-401F5DB95E16) claims the `SHOW PDBS` command works for any user with "DBA privileges", the support document "SP2-0382: The SHOW PDBS Command Is Not Available (Doc ID 2669189.1)" explains there is a bug and only SYSDBA can use that command.

As a workaround, you can query the same data with `V$PDBS` instead. (Although the results won't be formatted as nicely.)

```
select con_id, name, open_mode, restricted from v$pdbs;
```