# error ORA-65096 in Oracle 19C when I try to create user from java

Tags: oracle19c

I have installed oracle 19c on my laptop and started my script which creates some users. I get following errormsg:

Error Msg = ORA-65096: Ungültiger allgemeiner Benutzer- oder Rollenname

I researched this issue and founded this solution:
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

I tried this out from sqlplus and I can create user in sqlplus BUT when I create the user from the java script I get the same errormsg.

What can I check?
Any Idea?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle

Comment: as I mentioned I tried it out but no success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle-database)