# Creating a non-ORACLE_MAINTAINED user in ORACLE XE 18 via JDBC

Tags: sql, oracle, docker, oracle-xe, oracle18c

I want to create a user from JDBC (if possible) in an ORACLE Express database. That user can't have the `ORACLE_MAINTAINED` flag in the `DBA_USERS` view.

Trying `CREATE USER newuser IDENTIFIED BY xxx`, but it throws a `ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name`. To avoid it, I had to set the flag `ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=TRUE`, as other posts recommend. But that way, it's marked as `ORACLE_MAINTAINED`.

I'm connecting to the `xe` default database.

##### Context:

I'm working with the Oracle Docker image; it's for integration testing purposes. The metadata queries the app uses exclude `ORACLE_MAINTAINED='Y'` users/tables, and I'm not able to list them (not working with data, just metadata). I could remove the WHERE from the queries, but I would prefer to avoid it, and keep the app queries untouched.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle  That error normally indicates that you're creating a user in a CDB rather than in a PDB.  You'd almost always want to create users in a PDB not in a CDB.  I'd wager you want your JDBC application to connect to the appropriate PDB rather than the CDB you're currently connected to

Comment: How can I connect to the PDB? I only know the `xe` SID. I saw `XEPDB1` in the database logs, but I can't connect to it with the default users (SYS/SYSTEM). When I list `v$pdbs`, it's empty. Maybe there's not PDB by default? Should I create it first?

Comment: Which Oracle Docker image are you using?  If you're using this one (https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/post/deliver-oracle-database-18c-express-edition-in-containers) you should be able to connect to XE (the CDB) and XEPDB1 (the PDB) with the same `sys` password as documented in that article.  You'd want to connect to the PDB to create your user.  If you're using a different Docker image, the database could be configured differently.

Comment: Gonna check that, thanks. Well, the image I'm using is a corporative one... Not the Oracle official, not even sure if this image is based at all in the Oracle one, or if it is custom. Now I have doubts. Anyway, checking it, and going to do some tests. I'll update later!

Comment: First of all, if I run `select * from v$pdbs` and there are no rows, does it mean that there are not PDBs, or may be that the user doesn't have roles to see them?

Comment: Yes.  If you have permission to query `v$pdbs` from the CDB and there are no rows then there are no PDBs.  If you're using a corporate Docker image it would seem weird that it would be delivered with a CDB and no PDB.  I'd guess that maybe there was a separate install step to create the corporate-standard PDB.  Having everyone create their own PDB if you're doing integration testing seems like a recipe for some less-than-fun times.

Comment: After some research, it's based on: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.3.0
Not 100%, but most of the scripts are the same. I can't find any explicit reference to the PDB name or the PDB creation in that repo (I'm not an Oracle "expert" myself anyway, as you see)

Comment: The `createDB.sh` file in that directory appears to create the PDB.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found in in the `createDB.sh` script. I'm gonna report/talk it with the people in charge of this images... Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: Before closing the question... Is there a way to create a non-ORACLE_MAINTAINED user in a CDB?

Comment: I assume that there probably is.  But it's sort of like "Is there a way to change the oil in my car while I'm travelling down the highway?"  Technically, sure.  But it's not what a sensible person would want to do and would likely require bypassing a host of checks that are designed to make sure that doesn't happen and has a ridiculously high chance of ending up in a large ball of fire and much heartache.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Actually, the people that made the images I'm using already left, so there is nobody that knows them, and it will probably be a long way until they fix them, probably... But yeah, not the way to take. Thanks!

Comment: @Iván you you can, usually the only purpose of creating user in CBD is monitoring. So either you can use built in use DBSNMP, or you can use this `_ORACLE_SCRIPT` (undocumented hack).  Last option is to create a "Common user" i.e. an user whose name starts with `c##`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DA54EBE5-43EF-4B09-B8CC-FAABA335FBB8.htm

Comment: @ibre5041 Both options generated the user with the flag ORACLE_MAINTAINED when I tried them