# ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name - create role

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run the query -  `'create role warehouse_user identified globally'`
by JDBC (Dbeaver)
get error:

> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

I am running this by remote connection (automation).
some ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to run this under CDB.

You can go for connecting targeted PDB and then try it should work.

If you want to create a role under CBD please try with c## in the name prefix.

and another way is not recommended but you can go for alter session set `"_oracle_script"=true;` to take username/role name **without** prefix.