# Cannot create users in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, createuser

I'm running this line but can't seem to create the user, keep getting this error and haven't seen it anywhere online[See query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmc02.png)

```
CREATE USER Tshepo IDENTIFIED BY tmphoabc2023;
```

I was expecting this to just make the user but it keeps saying

> invalid common user or role name

Comment: Looks like you're logged into a CDB, while you should have been logged into a PDB. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle-database