# Oracle: "missing or invalid option" when trying to create user

Tags: oracle, procedure, execute

I have a table:

```
create table NHAN_VIEN (
    Ma_nhan_vien varchar2(5) not null,
    Ma_thu_vien char(3),
    Loai_nhan_vien char(3) not null,
    ...
    primary key (Ma_nhan_vien),
    constraint fk_NV_TV
    foreign key (Ma_thu_vien)
    references THU_VIEN(Ma_thu_vien),
    constraint fk_NV_LN
    foreign key (Loai_nhan_vien)
    references LOAI_NHAN_VIEN(Ma_loai_nhan_vien)
);
```

and a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HW31_CREATEUSER
AS
    CURSOR CUR IS (SELECT Ma_nhan_vien
                    FROM NHAN_VIEN
                    WHERE UPPER(Ma_nhan_vien) NOT IN (SELECT USERNAME
                                        FROM ALL_USERS));
    STRSQL VARCHAR(2000);
    USR VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
    OPEN CUR;
    STRSQL := 'ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = TRUE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(STRSQL);
    LOOP
        FETCH CUR INTO USR;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
            
        STRSQL := 'CREATE USER '||USR||' IDENTIFIED BY '||USR;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(STRSQL); -- These didn't work
        STRSQL := 'GRANT CONNECT TO '||USR;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(STRSQL); -- These didn't work
    END LOOP;
    STRSQL := 'ALTER SESSION SET "_ORACLE_SCRIPT" = FALSE';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(STRSQL);
    CLOSE CUR;
END;
```

I meant to create every user in NHAN_VIEN table.
But when I exec HW31_CREATEUSER, my sqldeveloper said:

```
BEGIN HW31_CREATEUSER; END;
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HW31_CREATEUSER", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 1
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
```

I can run my procedure if I delete the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(STRSQL);`
Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: If you add debugs, using `dbms_output.put_line` and enabling that in your client, then you can see the actual value for each STRSQL before it is executed, which will let you see the statement that errors. (Also _ORACLE_SCRIPT is intended for internal Oracle use, [it isn't something you should use casually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490385/266304)...)

Comment: user name and password must conform with [Schema Object Naming Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements008.htm#i27570). e.g. if they contain a white space or another invalid character then this will create a syntax error.

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried and it is the exact same statement like I intended to, I even copy that statement and run it, and of course, it work perfectly. I can only run that statement alone, not in a procedure.

Comment: it would be helpful to include the generated statement that fails in your question. Are you sure your code is exactly as shown - you don't add a semicolon on the end of the `create user` statement, perhaps?

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried to add semicolon to the end, but that too, didn't work. And yes, My work is as shown.

Comment: No, it should *not* have a semicolon. if your code was including/adding one then it would cause that error. That's the only way I can see the generated statement would work manually and not from your procedure. (Creating procedures in the SYS schema is generally not a good idea though...) Again, seeing the actual generated statement might reveal something.

Comment: and setting _oracle_script is not at all advised, and may raise problems with oracle support.

Answer (score 0):

You will need quotes around the relevant attributes (user/password) otherwise you can easily hit this error due to the data in your NHAN_VIEN source, eg

```
SQL> create user demo1 identified by abc;    -- abc is OK

User created.

SQL> create user demo2 identified by 9abc;   -- 9abc is not
create user demo2 identified by 9abc
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


SQL> create user demo2 identified by "9abc";  -- quotes to fix

User created.
```